# Flutterでログイン状態を保持する方法

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

#### 前提・実現したいこと

現在、Flutter+Firebaseを利用してアプリ開発について学習を行っています。
ログイン機能の一貫として以下の機能を実装したいと考えています。

- 初回ログイン時のみ、ログインページに遷移しログインを行う
- ログアウトしない限り、アプリを終了した後にアプリを開いてもログインページに遷移しない

自分なりにいくつか調べ、それらを試したのですがそもそもログインページに遷移しませんでした。
試したコードは以下mainコードです。

具体的な方法としてどのように行うことで以上の機能を実装することができるのでしょうか？
また、現在FirebaseのEmailとPasswordを利用した機能を実装しているのですが、GoogleログインやFacebookログインの場合でも以上の機能を実装する際には共通の方法なのでしょうか？

Flutter初学者なのでわからないことだらけですがご教授いただけると幸いです。

#### 現在実装しているもの

- FirebaseAuthを利用したログイン機能
- FirebaseCloudStoreを利用したデータベース

#### 試したこと

- FirebaseAuthのCurrentUserを利用したログイン状態の確認

#### 補足情報（FW/ツールのバージョンなど）

**使用したもの**

- FirebaseAuth
- FirebaseCloudStore

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.

  final UserState user = UserState();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<UserState>.value(
        value: user,
        child: MaterialApp(
          //デバックラベル非表示
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          title: 'Flutter Demo',
          theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
            visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
          ),
          home: LoginPage(),
          initialRoute: "/",
          routes:<String, WidgetBuilder>{
//            "/": (BuildContext context) => LoginPage(),
            AddRecord.routeName: (BuildContext context) => AddRecord(),
            "/login":(BuildContext context) => LoginPage(),
            "/home":(BuildContext context) => PageManager()
          },
        )
    );
  }
}

class LoginCheck extends StatefulWidget{
  LoginCheck({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _LoginCheckState createState() => _LoginCheckState();

}

class _LoginCheckState extends State<LoginCheck>{

  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    checkUser();

    // TODO: implement initState


  }
  void checkUser() async{
    final UserState userState = Provider.of<UserState>(context);
    final currentUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    print(currentUser);
    if(currentUser == null){
      Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context,"/login");
    }else{
      userState.setUser(currentUser);
      Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, "/home");
    }
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          child: Text("Loading..."),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: "うまくいかない" が何にかかっているのかが分かりづらい印象です (ログインページへの遷移 or ログイン中は遷移しない etc...)。 / "自分なりに調べて試した" ことも、もう少し具体的に記載しておくと回答のヒントになるかもしれません。

Comment: 回答される方へ　https://teratail.com/questions/283813

Answer (score 0):

そもそも、Firebaseのイニシャライズは行っていますか？
FirebaseSDKを使用する場合、アプリ起動時に Firebase.initializeする必要があります

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

// Import the firebase_core plugin
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(App());
}

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  // Create the initialization Future outside of `build`:
  final Future<FirebaseApp> _initialization = Firebase.initializeApp();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      // Initialize FlutterFire:
      future: _initialization,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        // Check for errors
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return SomethingWentWrong(); //エラーページ
        }

        // Once complete, show your application
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
        //ここに、アプリの本体をおく
          return MyAwesomeApp();
        }

        // Otherwise, show something whilst waiting for initialization to complete
        return Loading(); //プログレスインディケーター
      },
    );
  }
}
```

https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/overview
⇨こちらで、詳細が記載されています

以下は、CurrentUserの判定の例です

```
    FirebaseAuth.instance
  .authStateChanges()
  .listen((User user) {
    if (user == null) {
      print('User is currently signed out!');
    } else {
      print('User is signed in!');
    }
  });
```

> ログアウトしない限り、アプリを終了した後にアプリを開いてもログインページに遷移しない

⇨FirebseSDKが自動的に、ログインの永続化を行ってくれます